# How to get S3 bucket's full URL for firewall?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using azcopy (Azure Copy) to copy data from an S3 bucket thru a proxy.  We cannot allow *.amazonaws.com or any wildcard.  The security team requires a rule for each bucket to prevent exfiltration to other buckets.

We tried `[bucketname].s3.amazonaws.com` and it failed.  The proxy log shows it blocked the URL of the bucket which is `[bucketname].s3.dualstack.[region].amazonaws.com`

How do I find the full URL of an s3 bucket if all I have is the bucket name and bucket names are unique?  I can't find the info in the Amazon S3 console.

Comment: Hi M Oore29! Amazon documentation has https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region to describe rest endpoints to S3 storages. You could try to use them for your FireWall policies.

Comment: Thanks John.  Will be using the s3 endpoints in the above link for the firewall policies.

Answer (score 5):

The format is:

```
https://BUCKETNAME.s3-REGION.amazonaws.com/
```

For example:

```
https://foo42.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/
```

It is also possible for buckets to use `s3.amazonaws.com`, which will normally result in a redirect to the region-specific path.

URLs with `dualstack` relate to IPv6.

Comment: `${bucket}.s3.dualstack.${region}.amazonaws.com` is universal, since it supports both IPv6 and IPv4 (dual IP stacks). If that's what they're seeing in the log, they should allow that.  Which form is used depends on configuration options and/or design assumptions built in to the client.

Comment: Do you have an AWS Docs reference for the `https://BUCKETNAME.s3-REGION.amazonaws.com/` format?

Comment: @Andrew [Amazon S3 Path Deprecation Plan – The Rest of the Story | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)